# What is the <isindex> element in HTML?

Tags: html, html4

Apparently after doing a little research on the HTML `<head>` element I learned of the semi-existence of the `<isindex>` element and how it seems to have never been fully implemented...  I believe.  What was the intention behind this element and why was it deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/isindex) reference:

> `<isindex>` is an obsolete HTML element that puts a text field in a
>   page for querying the document. `<isindex>` was providing a single
>   line text input for entering a query string. When sent, the server
>   would return a list of pages matching the query. It supports depended
>   on both the browser and the server to react to the query.
>
> `<isindex>` is deprecated as of HTML 4.01, because the same behaviour
>   can be achieved with an HTML form.

Comment: Nice link!  And apparently there is more to it.  I don't quite understand the connection between nodes, documents, anchors, and links in the context of how they talk about `<isindex>` in the History section of the article.  Interesting!